# recursive function and mysqli close error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to generate a user id and associated 6-digit token for every user.
The values have to be both unique for active users. To ensure uniqueness I use the corresponding functions recursively.

The values are generated on page load. My script works at it should except (mostly) when I reload the page fast it gives errors. Except when I remove the `mysqli_close($dbLink)` statement. Is the problem in the fact that I close the link or in the fact that the functions are used recursively, a combination or could it be something completely different?

The error:

```
Warning: mysqli_prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\functions.php on line 68

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\functions.php on line 69

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in     C:\xampp\htdocs\project\functions.php on line 70

Warning: mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\functions.php on line 71
```

The code:

```
$user_id = generateUserId();
$token = generateToken($user_id);

function generateUserId(){
    global $dbLink;

    $user_id = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(128);
    $user_id = hash('md5', $user_id);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}' AND user_active = 1";
    $result_set = mysqli_query($dbLink, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_set) != 0) {
        generateUserId();
    }

    return $user_id;
}

function generateToken($user_id){
    global $dbLink;

     //generate Token with different numbers
    $numbers = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    $token = array();

    while (count($token) < 6) { 
        $number = array_rand($numbers);
        if (!in_array($number, $token)) {
            array_push($token, $number);
        }
    }

    $token = implode($token);

    //check if token exists
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_token = '{$token}' AND user_active = 1";
    $result_set = mysqli_query($dbLink, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_set) != 0) {
        generateToken($user_id);
    }

    //save token and user id in database

    $query = "INSERT INTO users ";
    $query.= " (user_id, user_token)";
    $query.= " VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbLink, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $user_id, $token);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_close($dbLink);

    return $token;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the fact of closing the link, you should close it after the call of the function, not inside.

BTW, if you want to close it inside the function, take in account of not do any kind of sql statement or function after the call of your recursive function.

What I would do would be to extract this code:

```
//save token and user id in database

$query = "INSERT INTO users ";
$query.= " (user_id, user_token)";
$query.= " VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbLink, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $user_id, $token);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

outside your function, this way you never use that link after have closed it.

Also... if your function does recursion for.. lets say 10 times, there is non sense in inserting that value 10 times, isn't?

Even more simple, you can insert it in the base case just adding an else:

```
function generateToken($user_id){
global $dbLink;

 //generate Token with different numbers
$numbers = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$token = array();

while (count($token) < 6) { 
    $number = array_rand($numbers);
    if (!in_array($number, $token)) {
        array_push($token, $number);
    }
}

$token = implode($token);

//check if token exists
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_token = '{$token}' AND user_active = 1";
$result_set = mysqli_query($dbLink, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_set) != 0) {
    generateToken($user_id);
}else{

  //save token and user id in database

  $query = "INSERT INTO users ";
  $query.= " (user_id, user_token)";
  $query.= " VALUES (?, ?)";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbLink, $query);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $user_id, $token);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_close($dbLink);
}


return $token;
```

}

Comment: Did I understand the recursion function wrongly? I figured in my code that the values are only inserted in the database when they are unique. So only once. And after that the link is closed and the value returned. Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: I suggest you to do a trace and imagine you wouldn't find that unique token for 3 times.